# Utilização da API dos correios com o AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Estou praticando ajax utilizando a API dos correios. Consegui! Porém acontece essas 2 situações:

1- Fica preso no bloco do else, então se eu colocar um CEP inválido após listar um válido não mostra nada, nem  msg de erro que coloquei pra aparecer, simplesmente nada, só se colocar um válido novamente.

2- Não sei se é o jeito da minha validação tosca ou tenho que colocar algo a mais... que quando mostra os dados e quero mostrar outro, não apaga o existente e sim vai colocando abaixo do que tava e assim sucessivamente.

Código:

```js
// Início.
           $('form').on('submit', (event) =>{                 
                event.preventDefault();

                // Pegando o valor digitado do usuário.
                var cep = $('#cep').val();

                // Validação do cep.
                if(cep.length != 8){
                    $('p').css({color: "red"})
                    $('p').html("CEP não existe.");
                }else if(isNaN(cep)){
                    $('p').css({color: "red"});
                    $('p').html("CEP inválido.");
                }else {

                    // Criando uma URL.
                    var url = "https://viacep.com.br/ws/" + cep + "/json/";

                    $.ajax({

                        type: 'GET',                          
                        url: url,                            
                        dataType: "JSON",                                                         
                        success: (resp) =>{
                            for(var i in resp) {                                    
                                $('#div').append("<h4>"+resp[i]+"</h4>");
                            }
                        },
                        error: (resp) =>{
                                $('p').css({color: "black"})
                                $('p').html("Error: ".resp);                            
                        }                            
                    });

                }

            })
```

Comment: não tendo nada a ver com a sua pergunta, o meu resultado final seria algo do tipo https://jsbin.com/sayozuk/2/edit?html,js,output ... espero que de para aprender um pouco :)

Answer (score 1):

Quanto a sua primeira dúvida, nesse bloco de validação:

```
if(cep.length != 8){
    $('p').css({color: "red"})
    $('p').html("CEP não existe.");
}else if(isNaN(cep)){
    $('p').css({color: "red"});
    $('p').html("CEP inválido.");
}else {
  ....
```

Você poderia remover o último else, e sair da function caso alguma validação falhe, algo simples assim:

```
if(cep.length != 8){
    $('p').css({color: "red"})
    $('p').html("CEP não existe.");
    return;
if(isNaN(cep)){
    $('p').css({color: "red"});
    $('p').html("CEP inválido.");
    return;
}
```

Quanto ao segundo problema, como está usando o `append` para adicionar conteúdo ao div, sempre vai adicionar ao final, precisa limpar o conteúdo do div antes de começar, assim por exemplo:

```
success: (resp) =>{
    $('#div').html("");  // aqui limpa o conteúdo antes de adicionar as dados retornados
    for(var i in resp) {                                    
        $('#div').append("<h4>"+resp[i]+"</h4>");
    }
```

Além disso, se quier só mostrar o conteúdo, seria melhor fazer com um click simples num botão no lugar de um submit, isso é só uma sugestão.

Comment: em vez de `$('#div').html("")` podes usar `$('#div').empty()`

Comment: Muito obrigado, consegui resolver o segundo problema. Agora em relação ao primeiro com os if/else eu descartei, coloquei direto e preferi trabalhar com os erros que vem do códigos http. Porém setei no statusCode os possíveis erros HTTP, mas não cai no bloco, os erros só aparece no console log, como o 400, 404...

Comment: entendi, mas de qualquer forma se puder validar o valor antes de fazer a chamada é muito recomendável, evita fazer uma chamada ajax que vai dar erro, reduz tráfego desnecessário... pode ser que qualquer hora o serviço bloqueie as requisições erradas seguidas e acabe até bloqueando sua aplicação por um tempo, dependendo do que mandar na chamada pode até entrar numa blacklist, fique atento com isso ;)